# get user details after signing in with google using firebase & flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get the user details after the user signs with google using firebase in flutter. here is code I have and it successfully signs the user in, but when I access the details it gives me this message when I hover over the red line -
**Error - The property 'username' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'**

```
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user;
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      try {
        final UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final user = userCredential.additionalUserInfo.username;
        print(user);
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {

        } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {

        }
      } catch (e) {

      }
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the red line appearing under the user variable -
[image]

How do get all the details of the logged in user including the session info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see the error message is quite goode explained in it: The value `username` can't be used like that bevause the owner of that value can be `null` so yuo would need to check first if it is null or not.

Ti get the user data use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener:

```js
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

It would make the auth state management much easier for you and generalise the workflow for any provider you use. You can also capture with it a logout

Comment: Thanks @Tarik, that worked, one more thing to clarify,  should I be just using one button for signin & signup if I am using a provider. I have heard when the user is not in the system, when the user signs in, the system signs up the new user and then signs in automatically, is that true?

Comment: Yes that is true. For providers like Google, Facebook etc. a single button is enough. Just take care to capture potential errors. If a user has already used a provider the others could fail because a user with the same email but different provider already exisst. You would need to link those when the user is signed in. That is something the user would need to do when you provide the features for it.